# jquery pause/restart setTimeout when item clicked

Tags: jquery

I have the following Javascript function. Simply put it alternates between two "pages" every 10 seconds.

```
cs1.toggleDiv = function() 
    {
        var cs1timeout = setTimeout(function () 
            {
                $(".page1").hide();
                $(".page2").show();
                var cs1timeout = setTimeout(function () 
                    {
                        $(".page1").show();
                        $(".page2").hide();
                        cs1.toggleDiv();
                    }, 10000);
            }, 10000);
        console.log(cs1timeout);
    }
```

But I am looking for a way to pause this when a button is pressed.

So something like:

```
cs1.pauseToggleDiv = function()
    {
        $('#PauseDiv').on('click',function()
            {
                clearTimeout(cs1timeout);
                //RESTART THE TIMEOUT IF CLICKED AGAIN
            })
    }
```

I've seen something about `clearTimeout`, but can't see how to apply it.

---

2016-02-24 12:42 Code updated above in response to below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setTimeout()` function returns an ID. Try this and check your console:

```
var myTimeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('do stuff');
}, 1000);

console.log(myTimeoutId); // should output a number
```

Now, if you pass that ID to the [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) function, it get's removed:

```
clearTimeout(myTimeoutId);
```

> **Note:** To be able to use the clearTimeout() method, you must use a
>   global variable when creating the timeout method:

This means you have to take **myTimeoutId** as a global variable so that this method can work properly

See also [why have to use global variable?](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp)

Comment: cheers, I tried that (see above), but I just get `uncaught reference error: cs1timeout is not defined`

Comment: That's because the `cs1timeout` variable is only available in the scope of the `toggleDiv` function. You'll have to create a global variable. See also the note @HimeshAadeshara added to my answer in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the timeout function in a variable in order to use the window.clearTimeout(timeout) method.

Something like:

```
var timer = setTimeout(function () {
    $(".page1").hide();
    $(".page2").show();
    setTimeout(function (){
        $(".page1").show();
        $(".page2").hide();
        cs1.toggleDiv();
    }, 10000);
}, 10000);
```

and when you want to stop it, you can call 
`window.clearTimeout(timer);`